# What will be an efficient way of converting a std::vector<Boost::any> to a std::vector<float>

Tags: c++, vector, boost-any

I can use a loop to copy elements from boost::any vector to std::vector of floats.

It is inefficient in the sense that there are 50000 values to copy, vector can grow beyond 50K and I have to save the to the disk in different folders. So it is a bottleneck.

So far the following wont work

```
vector<boost::any> v1
vector<float> v2

std::fill(v1.begin().v1.end(),v2) // This will not copy anything.
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by inefficient? If you want to turn a 50000-element any-vector into a 50000-element float-vector, you're going to have to copy 50000 elements.

Comment: The actual problem is that I have to do this repeatedly and save the vector to legacy std::vectors due do design constraints. Some vectors are beyond 100K or even more. So  the loop approach is basically a bottleneck at them moment.

Comment: Do you really need that vector of `any`? If you know that floats are stored inside, why to use `any`?

Comment: @DanielLangr - Again I have to stick with what is available. Last resort would be to ditch boost::any all together.

Comment: Ditching boost::any as you mention would be a better design. That class is meant for cases where multiple types must be handled together in a single container. If all contents are of the same type it only adds overhead and complexity without gaining anything.

Comment: @olm if you have e.g. a JSON document, you might find that you have something like a `ns::vector<ns::any>` that you know contains only `float`s

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/any/reference.html),

```
vector<boost::any> v1;
vector<float> v2;

v2.reserve(v1.size());
std::transform(std::begin(v1), std::end(v1), std::back_inserter(v2), 
[] (const auto& v1_val) { return boost::any_cast<float>(v1_val); });
```

will work.

... reserve(...) is the most important line here [ so that you don't reallocate memory when you add more and more items to the vector ].

To be honest, I don't really understand how to do it efficiently (memcpy-like), because you have a number of objects of different type, and to add it to another container, you have to cast EACH one to that type. You can't possibly do it more efficient than with a simple cycle or what other STL stuff provides (which is also a simple cycle anyway).

Comment: Let me give this a try sir!

Comment: To be honest, I didn't run that. Probably, there will be a problem with a cast from Boost::any to float. In that case, within lambda, you should write a code that converts a single Boost::any (v1_val) to a float (what is returned).

Comment: @Wajih std::transform IS a loop anyway, man.

Comment: seems that the implicit cast wont work. I get an error at compile time "[no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘boost::any’ to ‘const float&’
"

Comment: Sad that there is standard way from boost of such conversions

Comment: @Wajih `any` does not know what is stored inside due to _type erasure_. Consequently, implicit cast can't work. You need to cast explicitly. (At least with `std::any`. I am not that much familiar with `boost::any`, but I guess they are the same in this aspect.)

Comment: return boost::any_cast<float>(v1_val); should work

Comment: @Wajih Answer edited to apply fixes and a link to reference.

Comment: @LeontyevGeorgiy - I expected it to work, but still get almost the same compile time error "no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘boost::any’ to ‘const int&’"

Comment: Should there be a way using std::vector::data pointer?

Comment: const int? We were working with float, af far as I thought...

Comment: The only way of using it is to roll through its data pointer with a cycle and convert all items manually.

Comment: BTW, this is hardly an answer, since its solution is based on copying, which OP wants to avoid.

Comment: I don't think you need to wrap `boost::any_cast<float>` in a lambda, it's a callable already

Comment: @LeontyevGeorgiy yes we are working with floats. I dont understand why it gives me a compile error for const int&

Answer (score 2):

Your problem cannot be solved without copying. When you store some floats into a `std::vector<boost::any>`, those floats will be stored in memory at completely unrelated places. This is caused by the applied *type eraseure* technique.

Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/a91qWazK7

You can observe that those floats have different addresses than are the addresses of `any` objects inside a vector. This means that the floats are not stored in the vector's buffer itself. (In theory, they could be stored in this buffer if some *small buffer optimization* technique would be applied by `boost::any`, which doesn't seem to happen. However, even then, this wouldn't help since the elements wouldn't be store contiguously in memory.)

*Bottom line:* If you need to get floats stored in `std::vector<boost::any>` to `std::vector<float>`, there is no way to do that without copying them.